# How to have LTS+Livepatch at the OS installation step?

Tags: system-installation, lts, canonical-livepatch

In relation to my [previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465557/how-to-ensure-compatibility-between-the-kernel-version-and-the-livepatching-with).

I would like to know how I can have LTS + Livepatch enabled at the OS installation step?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You have to complete the Ubuntu installation and reboot in order to enable Livepatch.